# Pass form data as parameter to Symfony2 controller function via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I think this is one of the more complex tricks to get right and therefore I have decided to elicit the help of the very knowledgeable people on StackOverflow. My scenario is as follows: I have two entities, a user and an account. A user is always linked to an account upon registration (and depending on the type of user, might be linked to more than one account. Upon registration the function saveUser() is called (via ajax from frontend) and the submitted form data is retrieved from the Request Object. This data is then passed to the function saveAccount($data) (which is called in the saveUser() function) in the form of a parameter and the account is created (sometimes called more than once with different data sets to create various accounts), which is linked to the user.

Now I want to create an account from my admin panel without creating a user, so I want to call saveAccount($data) directly via ajax (from frontend) and pass the form data to it as a PARAMETER (instead of retrieving it in the function via the Request Object), so that I can use the same saveAccount($data) function and that I do not have to create a saveAccount() which works the the Request variable. Does this make sense? Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing this?

I did not post any code, as I did not see the need for it, this is more a conceptional problem, but if you require the code that I have thus far or if anything is unclear I will be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instances where a controller function can be called either via AJAX with form data or internally by a another controller function the following solution works:

```
public function saveAccount($data = null)
{
    if (empty($data)) $data = $this->getRequest()->request->all();
    ...
}
```

Then you can pass an array to the controller function in the same format as your form data array and it will use that data if passed to the function, otherwise it will retrieve the REQUEST (form) data.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any `saveAccount` method, you just rely on relationships between entities, i.e. on a `setAccount` method, or to a `addAccount` one in case you need to add an entity to a `Collection`.

Then Doctrine will take care of saving and persisting everything.

For saving data, I would **always** rely on a RESTful interface [which you can create easily via [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle)], and send everything via ajax no matter what; you'll end up with a smoother interface and more maintainable code.

Comment: Ok, admittedly I am not a Symfony expert yet, but you explanation doesn't exactly make sense. My architecture is such that a user is an entity and a account is an entity and they are linked in a many-to-many relationship. So during my user created, I do use `$user->addAccount($account);` (sometimes more than once as a user can be link to multiple accounts), but as far as I know you must first create that account entity ($account) before you can link it, so I use $account = saveAccount($data).

Comment: You should create the account in the Controller then - entities should not be responsible for creating other entities. When you flush the `entityManager`, everything will be properly saved.